# Post-Commit Hook & Trac

Tags: svn, trac, visualsvn, post-commit

Having a few issues with my post-commit hook script and track - hoping someone can help.

The scripts all work fine - no errors - but for some reason trac doesn't update. I turned on logging and found this:

```
Trac[svn_fs] DEBUG: Subversion bindings imported
Trac[cache] INFO: repos rev [363] != cached rev [362]
2 Trac[cache] INFO: Trying to sync revision [363]
Trac[cache] DEBUG: Caching node change in [363]: (u'Max/test2.txt.txt', 'file', 'edit', u'Max/test2.txt.txt', 362)
Trac[main] DEBUG: Dispatching <Request "GET u'/report'">
Trac[report] DEBUG: Executing report with SQL "SELECT id AS report, title, 'report' as _realm FROM report ORDER BY report"
Trac[report] DEBUG: Request args: {}
Trac[chrome] DEBUG: Prepare chrome data for request
Trac[session] DEBUG: Retrieving session for ID u'max'
Trac[main] DEBUG: 173 unreachable objects found.
```

But then nothing updates in the tickets ? Using the standard scripts etc from Trac itself for post commit hook per this http://svn.edgewall.com/repos/trac/branches/0.11-stable/contrib/?

Any ideas?

**Edit: I have 3 users who are TRAC_ADMIN - not sure if there is a permissions issue? i.e. no anonymous users etc**

Answer (score 1):

Check the execute bit on the post commit hook.  Verify that the hook is named as specified by svn.  (Read the [section on hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) in the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).)